# How to push DetailViewController from selectedRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

When i click from my SecondViewController on a cell i want to go to my DetailViewController from the **Storyboard**.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked at row: %@", [barCodeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);


}
```

How do i push to the DetailViewController and send [barCodeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] with it?

EDIT :**Not working code..**

Code

```
/*DetailViewController *detailViewController1 = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController1 animated:YES]; 
[detailViewController1 release];
//[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];*/
```

[image]

Comment: /*DetailViewController *detailViewController1 = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController1 animated:YES];
    [detailViewController1 release];
    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];*/

Comment: But not working.. Is there a way that i haven't set the Nib Name, and do you know where i can set that? / check what the nib name is

Comment: try [self presentModalViewController: detailViewController1 animated:YES]; Let me know if it works..

Comment: Getting error in my edit: i posted the error message

Comment: Does DetailViewController xib exist?

Comment: Maybe do i need to tell that i dragged in my storyboard another viewcontroller and created a class for DetailViewController.. Than i set the custom Class of viewcontroller to DetailViewController

Comment: No thats what i just want to tell you..

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume **Listviewcontroller** is your First view controller which contain a tableview. From that on **didSelectRow** you want to push **Detailviewcontroller**.

**1**.First check that your root view controller is **Navigation Controller** or not.

If you are using storyboard, then first your rootviewcontroller must be **Navigation Controller**

To check go to **MainStoryboard** file.

it should be something like this.

-> Navigation Controller -> Listviewcontroller -> Detailviewcontroller

**2**. Once it is confirmed that your rootviewcontroller is **Navigation Controller**. then to navigate from one **Listviewcontroller** to **Detailviewcontroller** you have to use "**Segue**"

Set a new segue from **Listviewcontroller** to **Detailviewcontroller** .

To set a new segue **Ctrl-click on the prototype cell located in the Listviewcontroller scene and drag the resulting line to the Detailviewcontroller scene.**

Upon releasing the line, select the **Push** option from the resulting menu.

The storyboard will update to display a segue connection between the table view and the Detailviewcontroller.

To open a **Detailviewcontroller** It will be necessary to reference this specific segue. In order to do so give an **identifier**. Click on the **segue connection** between **Listviewcontroller** and **Detailviewcontroller**, display the Attributes Inspector (View -> Utilities -> Show Attributes Inspector) and change the Identifier value to "Detailview".

In **Listviewcontroller** Add below method.

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Detailview"])
        {
            DetailViewController *detailViewController =
            [segue destinationViewController];

            // and add any other code which you want to perform.

        }
}
```

For more information [See this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_TableView_Navigation_using_Xcode_Storyboards)

To add navigationcontroller in Tabbarcontroller......you can do like this added image. [image: . Just]

i think you need to see this link :  [In Storyboard with Navigation Controller and Tabbar Controller](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/)

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'Detailview'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

Comment: i added this code to call the function:     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detailview" sender:self.view];

Comment: added the storyboard segue like the image i edited in my question

Comment: is your "SecondViewController" on a cell you want to go to DetailViewController. is having a navigationcontroller in its root.

Comment: My SecondViewController is my tableView controller. The DetailViewController is my viewcontroller where i want to go to when i click on a cell from SecondViewController. How do i check if navigationcontroller in its root?

Comment: i edited my answer. i add a link from which you can understand more easily. it show you with graphics. to check "SecondViewController" is having a navigation controlloer.......check its previous view is navigation viewcontroller or not......

Comment: My first controller is a Tab bar controller

Comment: then also it is not a problem.......you have created a segue from Tabbarcontroller to "SecondViewController" right..?

Comment: i have created a segue from secondview to detailview. from tab bar controller to secondview is just movement from the tabbar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22974/discussion-between-babboe-and-femina)